# reading live numbers with python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to coding and only 13. I was just hoping someone could tell me if I can print a some text if the dB level got over a certain level, I was thinking you could get it from here

```
if RMSch1 > 0.000001:                                     
       txt = str(5 * math.log10(RMSch1)) + "000000"
       txt = txt[:6] + " dB"
   else:
       txt = "No signal "
```

thank you

Comment: Is` RMSch1` continuously updated by your code? If not, you need to create a loop that updates it, then checks if it is above your target level.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: yes RMSch1 is in a loop

Comment: Add `print(txt)`
This is a very basic question. I suggest you go through a basic Python tutorial first.

Comment: What is the actual requirement? Do you just want to print some statements if the value for the text variable is greater than a particular value?

Comment: thank you for helping me I got this one by my self